# Including columns using MAP and dictionary in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am trying to include a column in a dataframe. I am using `MAP` tool in order to add it because it should be referenced to one variable.

Here is the current dataframe:

```
  X      Y            Z
  xx    high         10
        slow         20
        fat          30
  xy    high         15
        slow         10
        fast         30
```

I would like to include a `column D` taking `X` as a reference. This new column should be based on a dict (dictionary) with the following values:

```
{'xx': -4.50, 'xy': -10.21}
```

So I did:

```
df['D'] = df['X'].map(dicc)
```

However, when I run the code a message appears `KeyError: 'X'` . Am I missing something in the code or it is an issue in the data type (str / float)?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** 
I get the dataframe from a *groupby* taking `X`and `Y` as reference (thanks for the comment).

Comment: `X` seems to be an index, not a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension to do it

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':['xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xy', 'xy', 'xy'], 
                   'Y':['high', 'slow', 'fat']*2, 
                   'Z':[10, 20, 30, 15, 10, 30]})

dicc = {'xx': -4.5, 'xy':-10.21}

df['D'] = [dicc[i] for i in df['X']]
```

e
Extra:If your df comes from a grouby and the code says an error because it can't find column 'X', it's because 'X' is now an index column. To fix that just say `df = df.reset_index()` to get your DF to look like the one in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), but first is necessary convert level of `MultiIndex` [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html):

```
dicc = {'xx': -4.50, 'xy': -10.21}

L = [df.index.get_level_values('X').to_series().map(dicc),
     df.index.get_level_values('Y')]

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(L, names = df.index.names)
#alternative solution
#df = df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(L, names = df.index.names))


print (df)
              Z
X      Y       
-4.50  high  10
       slow  20
       fat   30
-10.21 high  15
       slow  10
       fast  30
```